# jQuery Show/Hide Text Button onclik or Smooth Hide

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button

I would like to **make sure** which method is the best and if my code **is valid and good.**

I did not succeed in renaming the text **"hide contact" / "'show contact"** to see the result.

`.style.display = 'none';` seems a bit too brutal to me without an exit animation.

I opted for the "hide button" version
but if you know how to rename the button it will be a bonus.

I also have jerks on mobile (chrome), I can't understand why .slideToggle is not smooth everywhere.

[image]

**Method 1 : not working**

```
/* Show/hide rename button text  */ 
jQuery(document).on('click', '#TEST_BTN', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("TEST_BTN").click(function(){
            if ($(this).text() == 'show contact'){
                $(this).html('hide contact;')
            }else{
                $(this).html('show contact');
            }
      jQuery('#hidden-content').slideToggle('250','swing','hide');
     });
```

**Method 2 : working**

```
/* Hide show contact button */      
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  jQuery('#TEST_BTN').click(function(){
  event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("TEST_BTN").style.display = 'none';
      jQuery( '#hidden-content' ).slideToggle('250','swing','hide');
  });
});
```

Comment: shouldn't $("TEST_BTN").click(function(){ be $("#TEST_BTN").click(function(){ in your Method 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mmm click inside click for the same element?! it'll not work like this it will add another click event each time you click the element and this is what you'll get after some clicks

```js
var i = 0;
$('button').on('click' , function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    console.log(i++);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click Inside Click</button>
```

Your code should looks like

```
/* Show/hide rename button text  */ 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#TEST_BTN").click(function(){
            $(this).text($(this).text() == 'show contact' ? 'hide contact': 'show contact')
            $('#hidden-content').slideToggle('250','swing','hide');
        });
    });
```

I prefer to use classes instead of ids in this case .. It'll much easier especially if you've more than one card .. see the next simple example

```js
/* Show/hide rename button text  */ 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".TEST_BTN").click(function(){
     $(this).text($(this).text().toLowerCase().trim() == 'show contact' ? 'hide contact': 'show contact')
     $(this).closest('.card').find('.hidden_content').slideToggle('250','swing','hide');
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden_content{
  display : none;
  height : 100px;
  background : #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <button class="TEST_BTN">Show Contact</button>
  <div class="hidden_content">Contact Info</div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <button class="TEST_BTN">Show Contact</button>
  <div class="hidden_content">Contact Info</div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <button class="TEST_BTN">Show Contact</button>
  <div class="hidden_content">Contact Info</div>
</div>
```

**Note**: For `event.preventDefault()` you need to use `function(event){ event.preventDefault();`